# Why is Avg() faster than Sum()?

Tags: c#, sum, average, benchmarkdotnet

I've got code for test on BenchmarkDotnet..

And then I found that something felt wrong..

My projects version is

C# 11.0
.NET 7.0
Nuget Package BenchMarkDotnet 0.13.5

```
ReadOnlyMemory<float> readOnlyFloats;
ReadOnlyMemory<double> readOnlyDoubles;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        var floats = Enumerable.Range(0, ArrayLength).Select(a => rand.NextSingle()).ToArray();
        var doubles = Enumerable.Range(0, ArrayLength).Select(a => rand.NextDouble()).ToArray();

        readOnlyFloats = floats;
        readOnlyDoubles = doubles;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double Calc_WaveStatistic_Sum()
    {
        return readOnlyFloats.Span.Sum();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double Calc_WaveStatistic_Sum_Double()
    {
        return readOnlyDoubles.Span.Sum();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double Calc_WaveStatistic_Avg()
    {
        return readOnlyFloats.Span.Avg();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double Calc_WaveStatistic_Avg_Double()
    {
        return readOnlyDoubles.Span.Avg();
    }
```

and the extend method goes to

```cs
public static double Sum(this ReadOnlySpan<float> values)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        sum += values[i];
    return sum;
}

public static double Sum(this ReadOnlySpan<double> values)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        sum += values[i];
    return sum;
}

public static double Avg(this ReadOnlySpan<float> values)
{
    return values.Sum() / values.Length;
}
    
public static double Avg(this ReadOnlySpan<double> values)
{    
    return values.Sum() / values.Length;
}
```

For this code, I expect the `Sum()` method to be faster than `Avg()`
but result is
[image]

Avg() is excuting an extra calculation after the Sum() (divide by length).

So is my result right?

If it's right, why is it faster?

Comment: @Fildor does `ReadOnlySpan` have LINQ support?

Comment: @GuruStron ah, just saw it's actually ROSpan rather than arrays. Comment deleted.

Comment: Why haven't you used `values.Sum()` instead of iterating over the spans using a `for` loop for a fair comparison. Either that or calculate the sums using `for` loops when calcuating the averages?

Comment: @phuzi Um, OP is _implementing_ `values.Sum()` there..?

Comment: @AKX I'll get my coat!

Comment: @phuzi `Sum` in `values.Sum() / values.Length` should be the same `Sum` which is used in `Calc_WaveStatistic_Sum`.

Answer (score 9):

It is not.

First, you're performing a very small microbenchmark. Measurement error by the benchmarking harness is a non-neglible factor here. In case of the `float` version, the (mean) measurement error reported by BenchmarkDotNet is 7.67ns for `Avg` and 4.62ns for `Sum`. Just the error entirely explains the difference in mean time (7.67ns + 4.62ns = 12.29ns, and the difference in mean is 12.4ns).

In case of `double`, the error reduces the mean difference to 43.27ns. This appears more significant, but you need to remember that performance analysis is, by necessity, statistical analysis. The standard deviation reported for sum in this table is *huge*, 35.68ns. In statistical terms this means that the result is too noisy to be considered significant – the difference is almost in the range of standard deviation. There's a big chance a lot of the smaller results are simply flukes.

To eliminate those errors, you should simply increase the `ArrayLength`. You did not share its value, but I am assuming it is *very* small. Using an array that's 100x larger is going to push your results into the millisecond range, where deviations of a few nanoseconds won't influence the results too heavily.

Comment: Thanks.  As you said, increasing the ArrayLenth size resulted in Sum being faster.